# Maven Release Rollback filed

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, release, rollback

Can some one please help me with

run: ./mvnw -f  ${{ inputs.pom-path }} -B clean release:prepare release:perform release:rollback

When I am trying to add release:rollback in my github actions file I am getting below issue

Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M6:rollback (default-cli) on project

Please let me know how to resolve it?

Comment: First why has it failed? There is an output of the error? And why would you like to rollback which created a release during the same command line call?

Comment: When release fails, we are not rollbacking it and because release process is commiting stuff to the main branch it can leave that branch in messy state which can prevent next releases from working properly....for that reason I wanted to use release: rollback goal and I am using GitHub actions . Here I wanted to define rollback goal if release fails I am not sure how to define release: rollback command here below is my code      - name: Publish Service
        run: ./mvnw -f  ${{ inputs.pom-path }} -B clean release:prepare  release:perform  release: rollback

Comment: First what would it mean the release process fails? Some tests are failing? That should be checked upfront (green build!).. Rolling back a release make not really sense.. Furterhmore it would help to show the errors you get etc. output ?